# Is it possible to embed complex javascript onto onclick on the same html page

Tags: javascript, html

I need to inject a snippet of html code to a remote server. The html code contains an image and direct link to the image location hosted in my server. For example

```
<img src="path.to.my.server.gif" >
```

When the user click on my image I would like to send 2 tracking pixels (an http call) to my server and redirect them to another page.

```
<img onClick="do_some_javascript_here">
```

Normally if I server the web page, I have complete control over my js file and the job would be trivial, for example in angular

```
<img ng-click="doSomeJavascipt()>   

 $scope.doSomeJavascript = function() {

        $http.get(pixel_url_1)
          .then(function(){
              $http.get(pixel_url_2)
                .then(function(){
                  $window.location.href = some_url;
                })
          })
          .catch(); 
    }
```

but since I am not serving the page, I am not sure how would I do it.

Any advice would be appreciate it

Thanks

Comment: More information is needed to answer this question. How do you inject code into this page? Have you considered simply using an `iframe`? Why/why not?

Comment: What does "sending 2 pixels" mean? Pixels don't exist, they're colours on a screen, you don't send them from a client to a server. Also, what do you mean "you are not serving the page", whose page is it then? Because CORS and XSS prevention, if the site owner is even moderately sensible, will prevent your JS from even loading. You're essentially asking how to hijack someone's page.

Comment: @Miszy I am not allowed to use iframe due to constraint in spec. The injection of code is a agreement between the two servers, basically I send the html partial through post

Comment: You send HTML and JavaScript code through POST and the website blindly injects it? It's like you're asking for a trouble. I don't want to have anything to do with this.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans `pixel` is a technical term for http calls in my domain. The server that is serving the page is not my server, but other people's server, they will basically take my image and serve them.

Comment: Assuming this is something both parties are agreeing to, and assuming you are providing some sort of "plugin" to the other site, you could have a JavaScript plugin that adds the image (tag and all) to the other page - then you just assign event handlers as normal.

Comment: @Miszy tracking pixels are well known technologies in the ad industry, I assure you this is not illegal. However I understand your concern, and its hard to prove otherwise either

Comment: @TiesonT. The only javascript code I can provide is through the onClick in the html partial

Comment: What is the "html partial"? You can only reference a function name in onclick, so the function has to exist in a script defined somewhere on the page.

Comment: @testing this is a security breach waiting to happen. My advice: walk away, this is a lawsuit timebomb. All you need is someone to compromise your server, and done. All your clients will be calling their lawyers (and no, you are not more secure than the rest of the world is good at hacking, social engineering, etc). Follow best practices instead, and read up on web security. [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) is a great place to start, particularly their [top 10 dangers](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10). You're doing number 3.